# List of functions using Dbghelp.h

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

I want to print function names (imported, exported, normal/local functions) but not variable names and so on.

[SymEnumSymbolsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symenumsymbols) enumerates all symbols, but I only want functions.
Also can not find how to distinguish functions and variables inside [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nc-dbghelp-psym_enumeratesymbols_callback) function.

Is there a way to enumerate only functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SYMBOL_INFO` passed to your callback has `Flags`, and there is `SYMFLAG_FUNCTION` for functions